# Why does separating variables in the spherically-symmetric TISE work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, mathematics, differential-equations

When solving the one-particle Schrodinger equation for a spherically symmetric potential, we use the substitution $$\psi(r,\theta,\phi) = R(r)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$$ in order to solve. However, I am almost certain that we must tacitly be appealing to some facts from the theory of differential equations to guarantee that we obtain a complete set of eigenfunctions by doing this. That is, that in doing this we don't "miss" possible eigenfunctions. Can anyone supply a reference or a quick demonstration of this? I did not immediately find anything and don't have the requisite background in analysis.

Comment: Can you explain a little more, perhaps in an answer? Since what you've said is largely above my head, I guess what I want to confirm is whether my assertion in the OP is true: that is, that I don't "miss" any solutions by using this ansatz. @TobiasFünke

Comment: From my understanding we're just lucky they end up being eigenfunctions of anything. Separation of variables is largely a guess (an educated guess, but still, a guess); if it works, hurray, if it doesn't, keep it up

Comment: I mean, the fact they end up being a complete set is of course tied to the fact that they're related to a compact self adjoint linear operator and the spectral theorem does its work. So it's not that surprising; but the fact we can separate the solution like so, and the "operator factors nicely" is what's lucky about this method

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previos comment, as I think it is not very helpful here. In any case, have a look at [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/763354/why-if-separation-of-variables-gives-all-eigenvalues-of-hamiltonian-for-hydrogen). I really think it is a duplicate. There I also left some comments and links to Math SE, which might be helpful.

Comment: Also, you can rest assured you don't miss any solutions because of the theorem for uniqueness for ordinary differential equations, because we can factor the PDE into several ODE, if you find a solution it will be **the** solution

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo The hydrogen atom Hamiltonian is not even compact. Also the eigen**functions** /vectors do **not** form a complete ONB.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Why don't they? Are you saying it's because we're missing the unbound solutions, or is there something else you're alluding to?

Comment: @EE18 No, that's it! But of course your question can also ask: Do we get all bound state solutions from this ansatz (and by taking linear combinations/limits)?

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/688947/how-do-we-obtain-radial-part-and-angular-part-with-spherical-harmonics) elaborates my initial comment and might be useful.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I may be misremembering, but separation of variables leads to 3 Sturm-Liouville problems which are solved by the properties of compact self adjoint linear operators no? Those were the operators I was talking about. The eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonean may not for and ONB, but the eigenfuctions of these "separate" operators do form a basis of their respective subspaces

Comment: @EE18 See e.g. *Lectures on Quantum Mechanics. P.L.Bower. Chapter 14 and 15.* and also: *A Mathematical Primer on Quantum Mechanics. A Teta. Chapter 9* (especially 9.8, proposition 9.11 might be useful, but this deals with the hydrogen atom in particular). Hope this helps.

Comment: "Do we get all bound state solutions from this ansatz (and by taking linear combinations/limits)?" And to this, you say, the answer is yes? Thank you also for the reference -- I will take a look, though I imagine I need to study a lot of math beforehand. I wanted to study Galindo and Pascual but found it too difficult mathematically (the rigorous theory of differential equations). @TobiasFünke

Comment: @EE18 I am not a mathematician, but as far as I know the answer is yes, indeed. Galindo Pascual is a nice reference usually. You are asking a mathematical question, so the answer will require a lot of maths ;). But I like these kind of questions. Maybe you are lucky and some mathematical physicists sees this and gives a nice definite answer.

Comment: You are appealing to the special form of the Laplacian and the potential  in spherical coordinates. Write it down.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I’m not asking if a separated solution works (the ansatz clearly does), but whether it lets us capture all such solutions. Perhaps I am misunderstanding you though.

Comment: You are asking whether a non separated solution cannot exist given the particular factored centrifugal potential coupling radial to angular functions.

Comment: I suppose that's one way of phrasing it, yes! @CosmasZachos

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are asking why the operator
$$
-H=\nabla^2 -V(r)= -V(r) +  {1 \over r^2}{\partial \over \partial r} \left(r^2 {\partial \over \partial r}\right) + {1 \over r^2 \sin\theta}{\partial \over \partial \theta} \left(\sin\theta {\partial \over \partial \theta}\right)
+ {1 \over r^2 \sin^2\theta}{\partial^2 \over \partial \varphi^2} \\
\equiv G(r) - \frac{L^2}{r^2},  
 \\ \hbox{where} ~~ L^2 = -  \left(\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \left(\sin(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right) + \frac{1}{\sin^2(\theta)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}\right), 
$$
*only* admits eigenfunctions of the type $R(r) a(\theta, \varphi)$.  (There is a wrinkle given degeneracy: cf the last paragraph.)

This appears like a feature of the Laplacian in spherical coordinates, where two of the variables, the angular ones, appear in a special factorized form w.r.t. the radial one, *r*, the centrifugal barrier.

Note if, for some absurd, fantastical, reason,  they entered in more complicated forms, such as arbitrary $f(\theta, \varphi)g(r)+h(\theta, \varphi) k(r)$, no factorizable eigenfunctions would be warranted. The factorization Ansatz makes sense when the well-known eigenfunctions of $L^2$  produce an effective constant for its eigenvalues $\lambda_l$ in the radial equation, which can then reduce the Hamiltonian to $H(r,\lambda_l)$, a one-variable spectral problem. As things stand, the radial eigenvectors depend on the constant $\lambda_l$, because of the reduced ODE involved.

This is not to say the factorized centrifugal barrier form is necessary for factorizing the eigenfunctions; you might have a hamiltonian involving more complicated blends of $L^2$ and *r*, which would admit factorized Ansaetze for a reduced radial ODE, or even more recondite functions of the two angular variables. It suffices to be able to supplant eigenvalues for operators of some variables to reduce the Hamiltonian to a one-variable system.

The converse, namely eigenfunctions of non-factored form, such as $f(\theta, \varphi)g(r)+h(\theta, \varphi) k(r)$, appears hard to analyze exhaustively;  even though, for special potentials such as the Kepler 1/*r* one, special symmetries such as LRL ensure degeneracy: you may have *several* $\ell$s for the *same* eigenvalue -*E*; so, as @Tobias Fünke points out in his trenchant comment, a linear combination of several different allowable $\ell$ angular functions times different suitable radial functions can sum to provide non-factorized bona-fide eigenfunctions—consider the unnormalized $\psi_{2,0,0}+\psi_{2,1,0} $. Note, however, all non-factorizable such are thought to be linear combinations of
the factorizable ones. (No proof here, but see [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.2651).)

Comment: I don't know if I understand. Take for instance the hydrogen atom. For a given $E$, there are more than one eigenfunctions of $H$, and any linear combination of the respective product functions is an eigenfunction again... So clearly not all eigenfunctions are product functions of $H$.

Comment: Yes, this is the model potential, (Kepler), with an exceptional  special symmetry (LRL) enforcing an $\ell$ degeneracy for a given E, so, a counterexample to the necessity of factorizability.  I should remove "worked hard enough".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it’s an assumption in the sense that you specifically search for solutions of this form.  There’s no guarantee of anything at that point: it’s just an ansatz, and it may not work.

What is remarkable is that this guess turns out to produce differential equations of the [Sturm-Liouville type](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory).  It then follows from the theory that the solutions are indeed complete.  In other words, even if you assumed a separable form, PDE theory tells you that *any* solution (separable or not) can be written as a linear combo of suitable products of the separable ones, and solving for each variable $(r,\theta,\varphi)$ separately produces actually does produce a complete set.

(Note that anoften-untold assumption is that the differential operator is self-adjoint, but that’s almost always baked in if you can reduce your ODE to the Sturm-Liouville standard form.)